# Python Mechanize Browser: HTTP Error 460

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to log into a site using a mechanize browser and getting an HTTP 460 Error which appears to be a made up error so I'm not sure what to make of it. Here's the code:

```
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open("https://foo.com/login")
br.select_form(nr=1)

br[br.form.controls[2].name] = "login@gmail.com" #I can't select the form or controls by name because they change every time
br[br.form.controls[3].name] = "mypassword"
br.method = "post"

response = br.submit()
```

And here's the error I get with mechanize debug messages turned on:

```
>>> response = br.submit()
send: 'POST /login/signin.logincomponent_0.signinform HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encodin
g: identity\r\nContent-Length: 599\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5
.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 F
irefox/3.0.1\r\nHost: myaccount.foo.com\r\nCookie: DC=origin1; STUB_SESS=fil
ler%7E%5E%7E0%7Cguid%7E%5E%7E30909BA355883C551B421713700871E5%7E%5E%7E04%2F09%2F
2014; TLTHID=33A41894C02B10C01D1CF554572C7A31; TLTSID=FFDDD892C02A10C01C0BF55457
2C7A31; STUB_SESSION=filler%7E%5E%7E0%7Cstub_sid%7E%5E%7E0%7E%5E%7E04%2F09%2F201
4; JSESSIONID=B6E04AC06D5885942E299F67EE421640\r\nReferer: https://myaccount.foo
.com/login/Signin?\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\
ntLGGfIeGONQt=H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWQvUoDURCFx0AQEmwEa1ES7G4sTKNVCgUhkeBqLbN3Z9cr98%2B5
N25sfBSfQPISKex8Bx%2FA1spCsxo7w9p%2BzDnfYZ7eoFl2YDdRhVX2ULtCWemMd5ZsvNoXFSCDSgeG
vuNCoEd5TSKipxD5vi%2BkY9IqFSkGEoP0C6KMJ4p01kkoTnz3ct5%2B3Xr%2BaMDaENrS2chOn6GhCJ
vDG7zDnkZb9JLIyhZHUx%2BhVVmPF9ba2wb%2F3TZmJymEZJIaFYJydj7LDvL3x5cGwNSXe9Bd6fUYQu
k4C7fwABBho6LjH1o7vkg3yx3Y%2Fus6GqZc%2FWrWL0bnlJ9mNSLf1Sv%2Bx2TIpMSGlu2tJRpRvWDl
%2BATZ7YRMRAIAAA%3D%3D&GkhkHrHNkEGO=N&NgSEvMJNtPPU=login%40gmail.com&tl
BhliqPEpQP=mypassword&NTFAoHFKrewo=184f4acf-1300-4e65-a81d-3092301d87c213970777534
13&signIn=signIn&shs8q2kGs88H=1979975621'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 460 Unknown\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Content-Language: en
header: Cache-Control: no-cache
header: Cache-Control: no-store
header: Cache-Control: must-revalidate
header: Cache-Control: max-age=0
header: Cache-Control: s-maxage=0
header: Cache-Control: private
header: Expires: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 21:09:40 GMT
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 21:09:40 GMT
header: Connection: close
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 460: Unknown
```

Any idea what could be causing a 460 error? I tried using the submit button on the page instead:

```
response = br.form.click(br.form.controls[6].name)
```

but I don't think that I'm using br.click() properly here?

Comment: Can you perhaps ask the person or people maintaining the site you're trying to scrape? The problem, as you correctly point out, is that 460 is not a publicly-defined error. It is an error in the 4xx "Client Error" series, which means (presuming the developer chose it for that reason) that there is something the application does not like about your request. However, it seems like that's something only the person who developed it could answer.

Comment: What's scary is that I actually recognize the website just from what's posted. (And you're right, selenium is a good option)

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the website was using Javascript as part of the login authentication mechanism and therefore Mechanize can't properly emulate a browser. I switched to Selenium which was able to handle the javascript and get me logged in successfully.