# HTTP response code of text file is 460 when file contains 1.0.2?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

I'm using an HttpsURLConnection to grab the only line in a text file hosted on Dropbox, as an update checker (for a Minecraft mod). The relevant code is below:

```
 URL url = new URL(linkToVersionFile);
 HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setConnectTimeout(999);
 int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Normally, this works fine. Except, however, if the text in the file is "1.0.2". When it's 1.0.2, it returns the 460 response code, which I cant seem to find in any list of response codes. The accompanying response message is "Restricted" though.

If the file contains "1.0.1", "1.0.3", "1.1.2", "1.2.2" or even "2.0.2" it works just fine. Nothing changes but the 5 characters located in the file. The same thing happens if different files are used, and given the text "1.0.2", so it's not a corrupt file.

While I can get around it by either avoiding 1.0.2 and moving straight to 1.0.3, or writing it as "102" instead, it's just such an usual problem that I was wondering if anyone had an explanation :P

If more information or test results is required, let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how are you modifying the text file?  What is the name of the file?  Is everything exactly the same except for changing the content of the file?  And here is something about the 460 code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972902/python-mechanize-browser-http-error-460

Comment: did you really tried to change the text on that exact file and after that it worked? or you didn't text inside that specific file?

Comment: @RichardChambers I modified it using both notepad and Notepad++. Changing the file name doesn't make any difference (as I have 4 different mods checking for updates, with different files, and setting any of them to 1.0.2 produces the same result). Everything about the file is exactly the same except the 5 characters in it ("1.0.2", "1.0.1", etc.)

Comment: try the workaround to confirm. change the text of that exact file and tell us the results.

Comment: Sounds like a dropbox bug for me.